# M620 Blade Servers Not Accepting Ubuntu 16.04 as the new OS

Tags: server

Working on a server with m620 blades. It has a CMC with idrac. we are trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 however whenever we boot to a drive it goes through the normal install process and says install completed. The problem comes in when it restarts, the system will go through the regular Dell start-up process and go right back into the old OS (ESXI) and not Ubuntu 16.04. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are the drives set in RAID?  Try setting the boot in the BIOS to the other hard drive.  Chances are, the ESXi is installed on the other drive and that is the one that is set for booting.  Try maybe formatting both drives before installing.  PowerEdge servers should be able to run Ubuntu.

Comment: Just some more thoughts here.  Check if you can get `megacli` installed in a live environment so you can run a command like `megacli -AdpBootDrive -get -a0` which should show you what the boot drive is set to.  You can change it from the first drive (0) to the second drive (1) with the following command:  `megacli -AdpBootDrive -set -L1 -a0`.

Answer (score 0):

So the EXSi was actually on an SD card on the back of the blades. we were not able to disable it but what we did do is through the system BIOS settings change the order in which the system boots from the hard drive, with Ubuntu, rather than the SD card with EXSi.